# "Обход" атрибута style (html)

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Движок генерирует картинку со атрибутом style, в котором заданы не нужные мне стили. CSS естественно не применяется. Как не вмешиваясь в файлы CMS картинке применить свои стили?

Comment: Не помогло

Comment: а нет. Все ок. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**

```
$('img').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

добавь их в самом конце страницы
тогда стили цмс закроются твоими

Comment: И ваше не помогло